# ImageView over gallery not clickable

Tags: android

I have a full screen gallery with `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Over that gallery I have a linear Layout with 3 ImageViews. I have allready mde the imageviews clickable, but when I click on them, the `gallery.setOnItemClickListener` is what is activated. How can I get he ImageViews clickable??

Tha layout complete layot is verry complex so I'm putting an image of the relevant part.

[image: LayoutDescription]

In the code I have:

```
    ImageView prev = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previousImage);
    ImageView play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playAllImages);
    ImageView next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nextImage);

    prev.setClickable(true);
    prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YADA YADA YADA ...
        }
    });

    next.setClickable(true);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YADA YADA YADA ...
        }
    });

    play.setClickable(true);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            YADA YADA YADA ...
        }
    });
```

I also have the listeners of the gallery:

```
_horizGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            YADA YADA YADA...
        }
    });


    _horizGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            YADA YADA YADA...
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                YADA YADA YADA...
            }
    });
```

The xml is something like this (I took out some non relevant parts to make it smaller for practical use):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:background="#11000000" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:weightSum="1.0" android:id="@+id/layoutToScrollDown">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.1" android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="30dp"  android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:padding="1px" android:id="@+id/previousImage"> </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.4" android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="30dp"  android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:padding="1px"  android:id="@+id/playAllImages"> </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="0.1" android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="30dp" android:layout_height="30dp"  android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:padding="1px"  android:id="@+id/nextImage"> </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<com.pixable.android.ModifiedGallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.pixable.android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/HorizontalGallery"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:spacing="2px"/>
```

It's all inside a relative view that for some reason is not beine shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gallery is below your images in your layout XML file. This means the gallery is in front of your images in terms of clicking.

You need to place the gallery component before any of the images. Consider using a `RelativeLayout` as the outer element. Place the gallery component before the `LinearLayout` with the images in. Add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to the gallery, and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the `LinearLayout` container.

Also there's no need to wrap each `ImageView` inside a `LinearLayout` - that will just make drawing the UI of your app slower.

Comment: Than you, let me try this and look at how it goes, but I allready moved that so if it solves the problem I'm going to kill myself. About the extra Linear Layouts, in my app I have 5 images (code in the question bacame bigger than necesary), so I simplified for practical use, The layouts are needed to display the images with the necesary spacing.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Now I have to kill myself (joking). Strange thing is that I originally had the images on the buttom of the relative layout (I even opened the last version of the app just to make shure Ihad it like that before asking). Eclipse must have had a parsing problem (Something that has allready happend to me many times).

Answer (score 1):

I think because your call to `findViewById` only relates to the outer parent view i.e. your gallery, anywhere you click on it will trigger off the gallery's itemClickListener.

Also I think that wrapping each ImageView in its own LinearLayout is causing problems. You should consider to just have 1 LinearLayout with the ImageViews inside of it.

What you need to do then i think is to inflate the layout and then retrieve the ImageView's from that View to add listeners to it.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.id.layoutToScrollDown,null);
```

or inflate the view as follows:

```
View v = View.inflate(context,R.id.layoutToScrollDown,null);
```

or maybe even try findviewbyid:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.layoutToScrollDown);
```

and then get ImageViews:

```
ImageView prev = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.previousImage);
ImageView play = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playAllImages);
ImageView next = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.nextImage);
```

You can then continue following your code as normal.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's a preety good Idea, I'll try this after trying @Joseph opton. It doent add code, making the app faster. I wouldn't have thought of this,  so thank you verry much, might be helpfull for the future.